# Date format gone wrong in swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I need to set a date in medium format like: `Jul 17, 2016 4:30:00 PM`,
but I get `07/17/2016 4:30:00 p.m.`

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
this is my code:

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

 dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
 dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

 let mydate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

Comment: I am getting the correct output exactly as you want. I don't see why you're unable to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the code you are using does exactly what you need.

In case you need you can achieve this by using `MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a` as the format string for your formatter object.

Code follows:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a"
let mydate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
// "Jul 17, 2016 11:48 AM"
```

Comment: You missed the date.

Comment: @BhavukJain oops!!, fixed

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your date formatter locale to "en_US_POSIX" and you should also set your formatter calendar to ISO8601 to get the result you were expecting:

**Xcode 8 beta 2 • Swift 3**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .ISO8601)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))  // "Jul 17, 2016, 4:09:48 AM\n"
```

**Xcode 7.3.1 • Swift 2.2.1**

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))  // "Jul 17, 2016, 4:12:49 AM\n"
```